# can't support "npm link" added local package in vite-cli

Tags: reactjs, vite

I use the "npm link my-package" to redirect my node_module.
But I failed to run successfully with "vite dev".
Vite Could not resolve my local private package.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'my-package' of undefined.
```

However, it can work if i use "npm i my-package" from npm server.

OS: windows

Answer (score 9):

https://vitejs.dev/config/dep-optimization-options.html#optimizedeps-include

Add this to vite config:

```
optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['my-package'],
},
```

Comment: Didn't work for me with vite@2.7.10. In my `package.json`: "sanctuary-def": "file:../../opensource/sanctuary-def". In my `vite.config.js`: export default {
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['sanctuary-def']
  }
};

Comment: URL has changed slightly:
https://vitejs.dev/config/dep-optimization-options.html#optimizedeps-include

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and while `optimizeDeps.include` was recommended it did not work for me.

Initially I ran `npm link` in my package folder, then `npm link editorjs-media --save` in my project.

This left me with an entry in `package.json` like this `"@adampatterson/editorjs-media": "file:../_packages/editorjs-media",`

Building the project resulted in errors

```
error during build:
RollupError: "default" is not exported by
```

Installing from Git worked fine.

**What ended up working for me was:**

```
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['@adampatterson/editorjs-media']
    }
  },
  // ... other options ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue involving `npm link` used to temporarily use an unpublished version of a locally developed library for testing in a consuming application's project which happens to already use a previously published version of that library.

In my case, setting up optimizeDeps wasn't helping either for the issue wasn't about mixing commonjs with ES modules for all code is implemented as ES modules already.

However, the one sentence in that documentation for Vite's optimizeDeps might be important:

*When making changes to the linked dep, **restart the dev server with the --force command line option** for the changes to take effect.*

There is a cache in consuming project's **node_modules/.vite/deps** folder and in my case using `npm link` didn't trigger vite to update its cache automatically. If restarting with `--force` doesn't help either, try it the manual way and stop the dev server, remove all content of **node_modules/.vite/deps** and then restart the dev server. This was working in my case.